# -webkit-filter: grayscale() is causing me problems on hover css

Tags: css, webkit, hover

Hey so I am making tumblr themes and for some odd reason, the grayscale effect is only sometimes adding padding on some random elements on the blog including the images. It makes no sense that this is because of the filter, but when I turn off the filter, nothing like this happens. I have tried many different methods, I will list some below:

```
.gray {

 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.7);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
.gray:hover{

-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

----------------------------------------

    #content img {
 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.7);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}

#content:hover img{
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}

----------------------------------------

#content:hover img{
-webkit-filter: none;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
.gray {

 -webkit-filter: grayscale(.7);
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
transition: all 1s ease-in-out;}
```

I wont keep going because of redundancy, but you get the point! So I have images in the content ID and I am trying to get them to be black and white and on hover turn normal, which I did, but for some reason, it sometimes adds the padding on hover. Any clue as to why this happens or is there anything faulty in the way I am doing the grayscale?

Comment: Have you tried specifying `padding: 0` in the `:hover` sections since that's what the problem is?

Comment: yes, and it doesn't work

Comment: Can you post a Fiddle?

Comment: I made a fiddle with the code I used and there was no problem with it on the fiddle so it makes it seem like the issue would not be in the filter, yet when I disable the filter on the site there is no issue on hover (and there is still another hover effect). I am hosting the site [here](http://ryansthemetest.tumblr.com/). The hover effect may not cause an issue for you, it seems that it only happens for some people and not all the time.

Comment: Your site works fine. Which browser are you on?

Comment: I am on chrome. And that's what I am saying, for me it only happens sometimes. for some people it happens never. and for some people it happens all the time! I honestly have no clue how that's possible

Answer (score 0):

> I made a fiddle with the code I used and there was no problem with it

Seems to be some styles are overriding `:hover`. Try adding `padding:0`.

Comment: I have already linked it in a previous comment, but here it is again: http://ryansthemetest.tumblr.com/

Comment: Unfortunately there is no padding for me.

Comment: yeah, I don't understand why it only shows up for some people and only sometimes, it drives me crazy!

Comment: 'Some people' may be browser version but 'some time'? It's crazy but look for some jQuery conflicts. I have some experience like this before.

Comment: How could that be though? the jquery events that I have are not operating on the content with the gray class

Answer (score 0):

add following to css code for IE

```
.fmcircle_in span {filter: alpha(opacity=0);}

.fmcircle_out:hover .fmcircle_in span{filter: alpha(opacity=100);}
```